# Is it possible to have slight differences when running the same Simulink simulation twice?

Tags: simulation, simulink, numeric, solver

Assume that you have a Simulink simulation. You run it twice and consider a plot of a certain signal in time. Is it possible that there are small differences between the two signals?

A possible cause could be a variable-step solver.

Comment: Highly unlikely.  The solvers are deterministic, and the random number generators are reset to the same seed, so you should expect the same result every time you run the model.  If you are seeing differences then it must be something going on in the model.

Comment: I remember that I once changed the value of a variable that was not used in a Simulink simulation, yet it seemed to slightly influence the simulation result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all simulation parameters are the same between runs, if your simulation is complex, and uses custom blocks, such a thing is possible, if there is a bug in the initialization code.

With S-Functions, for example, you can chose if and how to reset internal state between simulation runs. With C code, it is easy enough to forget to reset something altogether, and end up with some uninitialized variable that contains garbage.

Another possibility is that something gets written into the workspace from the simulation, and is fed back into the simulation when it is initialized the next time.